# CMake Error ... No SOURCES given to target:

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I am trying to compile a custom package but I am getting some errors with CMake. The error is the following:

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'kate_global'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(kate_global)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- kate_global: 2 messages, 0 services
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at kate_global/CMakeLists.txt:140 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

  catkin::rosconsole::wrapped-linker-option0


  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at kate_global/CMakeLists.txt:140 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: control_node_kate


-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/catkin_ws/build
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I don't know what is wrong so I attach here CMakeLists and the directory of the files of executables:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(kate_global)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  controller_manager
  diff_drive_controller
  roscpp
  rospy
  message_generation
  std_msgs
  move_base
)

 add_message_files(
   FILES
   enc_msg.msg
   CAN.msg
)

 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

catkin_package()

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(
  control_node_kate src/kate_control_loop.cpp src/kate_hw_interface.cpp
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
    
target_link_libraries(
  control_node_kate
 ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )

install(TARGETS control_node_kate
   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
 )
```

Files listed

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws/src/kate_global/src $ ls -l
total 12
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 2450 Jun 11 12:53 kate_control_loop.cpp
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 8060 Jun 11 13:17 kate_hw_interface.cpp
```

I am working on Raspberry Pi OS (64 bits) using ROS Noetic.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.
Alessandro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356005/cmake-error-...-no-sources-given-to-target:/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2020-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-29**:
Please remove all the comments from your `CMakeLists.txt`. They are not needed and make it unnecessarily long.

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-06-29**:
Done. Thanks for the advice.

**Comment by [Jayanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/56229/jayanth/) on 2020-06-29**:
please refer to this answer
[https://answers.ros.org/question/244489/multiple-files-in-one-add_executable/#:~:text=Among%20those%20multiple%20files%2C%20only,file%20has%20the%20main%20function](https://answers.ros.org/question/244489/multiple-files-in-one-add_executable/#:%7E:text=Among%20those%20multiple%20files%2C%20only,file%20has%20the%20main%20function).

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-06-30**:
Respect to that answer, just the control_loop.cpp has the main entry, the hw_interface.cpp is called by an include file. Maybe I have to delete the add_executable of hw_interface? By the way, I have other similar project with that two add_executable and it compiles, so I don't know what is going wrong in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved creating a package from scratch using:

```
catkin_create_pkg my_package std_msgs rospy roscpp
```

Best regards.
Alessandro

---

Originally posted by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) with karma: 113 on 2020-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0